# How detect "Delete Deploy Key" event in GitHub?

Tags: github

Deleting deploy key cause many problems, like CI failure.
I want to detect and alarm it automatically.

My idea is watching audit log of GitHub organization, but no event comes when I delete Deploy Key. Is there any other idea to detect key deletion?

Comment: could you run a cron action periodically and detect its no longer there?

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks. It must enable me to detecting. However, I want to detect the event for all deploy key in the organization and not want to configure cron. In other words, I need some convenient managed service.